# Pyspark: For each month, get all the records of the current and previous month

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Input dataset:

```
+-------+------+--------+----------+
|     id|  site|due_date|year_month|
+-------+------+--------+----------+
|3360874|Mexico|21-06-23|   2023-06|
|3135684|Mexico|30-06-23|   2023-06|
|4020536|Mexico|14-07-23|   2023-07|
|3406187|Mexico|21-07-23|   2023-07|
|3921249|Mexico|24-07-23|   2023-07|
|3931545|Mexico|28-07-23|   2023-07|
|3372435|Mexico|31-07-23|   2023-07|
|3387147|Mexico|31-07-23|   2023-07|
|3921255|Mexico|11-08-23|   2023-08|
|3797741|Mexico|18-08-23|   2023-08|
|3662664|Mexico|30-08-23|   2023-08|
|3931383|Mexico|31-08-23|   2023-08|
|3931375|Mexico|31-08-23|   2023-08|
|3927073|Mexico|31-08-23|   2023-08|
+-------+------+--------+----------+
```

Output dataset:

[image]

for each combination of SITE and YEAR_MONTH columns, I need to retrieve all the records for the current month and also records from the previous month. For example for site = Maxico and Month = 07 and Year = 2023, we need to fetch records those of 07-2023 and also of 06-2023.

Trying out will cummulative, but I would require the record_id as well

Comment: Would you mind sharing what your expected result should be? I can interpret what you're saying a few ways and I'm not sure what you're really looking for, in terms of a result.

Answer (score 0):

Check below solution

`Logic` - Put `current month` & `previous/next month` values in array & then explode using `explode_outer` function. You will get expected result.

As per your output I have used `add_month(.., 1)` to match your expected results. If you want previous month you can change this to `add_month(.., -1)`

```
SELECT
  id,
  site,
  due_date,
  explode_outer(
    array(
      year_month, 
      date_format(
        add_months(
          date_format(
            year_month, 
            'yyyy-MM'
          ), 
        1), 
        'yyyy-MM')
      )
    ) AS year_month
FROM source
```

Output

```
+-------+------+--------+----------+
|id     |site  |due_date|year_month|
+-------+------+--------+----------+
|3360874|Mexico|21-06-23|2023-06   |
|3360874|Mexico|21-06-23|2023-07   |
|3135684|Mexico|30-06-23|2023-06   |
|3135684|Mexico|30-06-23|2023-07   |
|4020536|Mexico|14-07-23|2023-07   |
|4020536|Mexico|14-07-23|2023-08   |
|3406187|Mexico|21-07-23|2023-07   |
|3406187|Mexico|21-07-23|2023-08   |
|3921249|Mexico|24-07-23|2023-07   |
|3921249|Mexico|24-07-23|2023-08   |
|3931545|Mexico|28-07-23|2023-07   |
|3931545|Mexico|28-07-23|2023-08   |
|3372435|Mexico|31-07-23|2023-07   |
|3372435|Mexico|31-07-23|2023-08   |
|3387147|Mexico|31-07-23|2023-07   |
|3387147|Mexico|31-07-23|2023-08   |
|3921255|Mexico|11-08-23|2023-08   |
|3921255|Mexico|11-08-23|2023-09   |
|3797741|Mexico|18-08-23|2023-08   |
|3797741|Mexico|18-08-23|2023-09   |
|3662664|Mexico|30-08-23|2023-08   |
|3662664|Mexico|30-08-23|2023-09   |
|3931383|Mexico|31-08-23|2023-08   |
|3931383|Mexico|31-08-23|2023-09   |
|3931375|Mexico|31-08-23|2023-08   |
|3931375|Mexico|31-08-23|2023-09   |
|3927073|Mexico|31-08-23|2023-08   |
|3927073|Mexico|31-08-23|2023-09   |
+-------+------+--------+----------+
```